# how to create an installer on mac which can install prerequisites required

Tags: macos, installation

Is it possible to create an installer on mac which checks for the required software? 
For example,  If user doesn't have required software say xcode,  installer should automatically download and install it. if xcode is present in the system, it should proceed with next prerequisite software.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried writing the script yourself? we arnt here to write it for you :) give us a few examples of what you have tried

Comment: No i have n't tried any script. As i am new to this topic, Path showing how to proceed with it would be really appreciated.  I will do rest of things by my own

Comment: I would recommend you do some research look on google at places to start, then try to build it and then come back to SO if you need to

Comment: If you are looking for a package which checks and installs Xcode n all, then I must tell you, it's going to be difficult. Since you cannot bundle Xcode with your installer. Otherway, you can write a helper script which checks like what is installed and what is not. Just similar to 'appium-doctor'

Comment: Thanks @VighneshPai. Yes  I am looking for something which works exactly like Appium doctor.